# Hide button of same GUI from another button in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one form (say `form1`) that has 2 buttons (say `button1` & `button2`). When I click on `button2` the same form i.e `form1` should open but the condition is when `form1` opens for the second time both `button1` & `button2` should get hide. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Simply hide both buttons when instantiating the form for the second time:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var secondForm1 = new Form1();
    secondForm1.button1.Hide();
    secondForm1.button2.Hide();
    secondForm1.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `static` instance counter and increment it in the constructor. If this counter exceeds 1 then hide the buttons in the constructor:

```
public static int InstanceCount = 0;

public Form1()
{
    InstanceCount++;
    InitializeComponent();
    if (InstanceCount > 1)
    {
        this.button1.Hide();
        this.button2.Hide();
    }
}
```

You could then reverse the process in the closing event and count backwards each time a `Form1` is closed:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
     InstanceCount--;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses.
But unfortunately it did not work for me. whenever I try to hide buttons it shows that change in the form1 that open for the first time. Actually I want to hide buttons of the gui which is open for 2nd time.

Comment: @Pooja when you open the form for the first time your buttons are hidden (if you use this code )? did I understand you correctly? When I use it the buttons are gone only from the second instance on.